# Child Div appears on new line

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm having an issue with some child elements within a div. The parent div is the header, which is supposed to hold a three column header in theory. There is the left column, which will be a slideshow, the middle which will be a 20px divider and the right, which will hold informational text.

The issue I am having is that the only way I can seem to get the right column to stay inline is by telling the text to align right, but this doesn't work aesthetically because I need the text centered.

I wanted to just tell the DIV to float right, but when I do this the div always goes onto the next line rather than floating inside the header div. Here is the example of the issue (http://cbchaverhill.onedirectionconnection.com/), please ignore everything other than the header (haven't started working on those elements just yet).

Here is my CSS:

```
div#header {
clear: both;
height: 300px;  
width: 900px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

div#slide {
float: left;
clear: both;
height: 300px;
width: 590px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}

div#divide {

 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 20px;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 background: url(/wp-content/themes/cbc/divide.png) no-repeat;

}

div#cbcstuff{
display:  inline-block;
float: right;
clear: both;
height: 300px;
width: 290px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here is the coding of the header:

```
<div id="header">

<div id="slide"></div>
<div id="divide"></div>

<div id="cbcstuff">
Calvary Baptist Church<br>
Haverhill, MA 01832
</div>

</div>
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how I can get the right column to align right without having to align the text right?

Thank you for your time!

~Noelle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `clear: both;` in `div#slide` and `div#cbcstuff`. With that commands, you clear float styles.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "clear: both" from div#cbcstuff

Answer (score 0):

The clear:both; is the cause of the problem here.

> The clear property specifies which sides of an element where other floating elements are not allowed.

By stating both you are telling it that no other float elements are allowed on each sides, thus sending it under and outside the "container" div

[CSS clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)